# My app doesn't show anything in the iOS simulator

Tags: ios

I am learning about how this article 
[program description](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/01_StartingOut.html)
At the end of the page of Table View Controller you have to run you're app to see if everything works but i don't see anything in the iOS simulator besides that everything is black and at the top carrier and time.

One time i'm getting the error Locations[1203:fb03] Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
And another time

**App delegate header file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

UINavigationController *navigationController;

@interface LocationsAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator        *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;



@end
```

**App delegate Implementation file:**

```
#import "LocationsAppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"


@implementation LocationsAppDelegate;
@synthesize navigationController;

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc]
                                          initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
if (!context) {
    // Handle the error.
}
// Pass the managed object context to the view controller.
rootViewController.managedObjectContext = context;

UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                     initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
self.navigationController = aNavigationController;

[_window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];


[rootViewController release];
[aNavigationController release];

return YES;
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
// Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
[self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
if (managedObjectContext != nil)
{
    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

/**
 Returns the managed object context for the application.
 If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store    coordinator for the application.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
{
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil)
{
    __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return __managedObjectContext;
}

/**
 Returns the managed object model for the application.
 If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
{
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Locations"     withExtension:@"momd"];
__managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
return __managedObjectModel;
}

/**
 Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added     to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
{
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]    URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Locations.sqlite"];

NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]   initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
{
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}    

return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

/**
Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory   inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

**View controller header file:**

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {

NSMutableArray *eventsArray;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

CLLocationManager *locationManager;
UIBarButtonItem *addButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *eventsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *addButton;


@end
```

**View controller implementation file**

```
//
//  RootViewController.m
//  Locations


#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize eventsArray;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize addButton;
@synthesize locationManager;

- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager {

if (locationManager != nil) {
    return locationManager;
}

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
locationManager.delegate = self;

return locationManager;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
addButton.enabled = YES;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
addButton.enabled = NO;
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {


[super viewDidLoad];
// Set the title.
self.title = @"Locations";

// Set up the buttons.
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                          target:self     action:@selector(addEvent)];
addButton.enabled = NO;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

// Start the location manager.
[[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
self.eventsArray = nil;
self.locationManager = nil;
self.addButton = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
[managedObjectContext release];
[eventsArray release];
[locationManager release];
[addButton release];
[super dealloc];
}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}

   #pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc]  initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 */
}

 @end
```

Can someone please help me out??

Comment: Can you post the code of applicationDidFinishLaunching method for your application delegate?

Comment: Please edit the code into the question.  Comments don't allow for code formatting, making it very difficult to read.

Comment: i have put some code here but it is the same as the one in the link program discription

Comment: edit your question and add the code there itself. It is very difficult to read the code in comments.

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping me i have put the whole code here maybe someone can see what i'm doing wrong

Comment: The SIGTERM problem was when i stopped the iOS simulator before i stop the program in Xcode will generate such a problem. But the program still don't display nothing.

Comment: It shows now this problem when i run the program  Locations[1637:fb03] Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Comment: Try using self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController; instead of [_window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

Comment: I did change it but it still gives me the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I feel like Captain Obvious, but you forgot to set `window.rootViewController`.

Comment: In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method do `self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;`.

Comment: I did change it but still nothing happens. It still displays everything in black i only see carrier date an battery at the op of the iOS simulator. But i'm using Xcode 4.2 is has this maybe something to do with the difference between an empty application and a window based application that is in Xcode 4.1??? And one more thing i did change was that i have set the ARC off.

Comment: I have already fix the problem , a had to make an xib file instead and the "sigabrt" problem is when you're app crashes. When you change you're model you will have to delete you're old xml files in you're library otherwise you won't be able to run you're app anymore it will crash each time you run it